# How to determine if a property in PATCH request was explicitly set to null

Tags: c#, .net

I have a PATCH endpoint in controller with method taking `EditGroupApiCommand` as parameter:

[image]

In Swagger you can provide a JSON object with those parameters as such:
[image]

Regardless if the `Manager` property has been included in JSON and set to null or it was omitted,
In the controller I am receiving an empty guid.

I want to distinguish two cases:

- Manager guid has been omitted (then I skip any validation/actions)
- Manager guid has been explicitly set to null (I remove the managers)

Comment: You can set your Property to `Guid?` so you can receive `null` values. Then you can set it to `Guid.Empty` if you want to remove the managers. Not sending the `Manager` and sending it with a null value will otherwise both result in Guid.Empty in your case.

Comment: @RedFox so now, if in the JSON I will not pass Manager at all it will be null, but when I will pass `"Manager":null` it will also be null.  To remove the manager I would need to explicitly pass an empty guid.

Comment: Yes. Setting it to `Guid.Empty` when you want to delete it is the best way to distinguish between "activily setting it" and ommiting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Manager` property is a `Guid` which means it can not be null.
When the value is missing in the incoming data it will result in `default(Guid)`, same happens if it is set to `null`.

If you can change the `EditGroupApiCommand`, change the `public Guid Manager` to `public Guid? Manager`.
If you want to delete the `Manager` => set the Manager to `Guid.Empty`:

```
{
   "Manager": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

If it was ommited => it is null.

So you have to explicitly set it to `Guid.Empty` to distinguish thge use cases.